# How did Tony Stark synthesise a new element in Iron Man 2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, marvel, iron-man-2

How did Stark manage to create a new element after Jarvis said it was impossible to synthesise the atom? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Movie nonsense.  Artistic license, etc...

Comment: Didn't he have a snarky reply to Jarvis after that, as he got to work on it?

Comment: I don't see why it takes movie nonsense or artistic license for Jarvis to be wrong.

Answer (score 10):

JARVIS was using its existing knowledge & analysis on Vibranium structure given by Tony's father. And then, human brain came in. Tony Stark synthesized Vibranium using his table-top particle accelerator (not sure it was portable LHC, but it was impressive).

Comment: Note that we regularly synthesize transuranic elements with particle accelerators, so the idea isn't without merit.  What made it silly was the scale and the hand-hacked nature of it. And that Tony wasn't being cooked while the thing was running.

Comment: This is how the movie explains it. In reality he could have created a new element this way, but, creating a new atom on a Particle Accelerator only produces a few unstable atoms that tend to disapear (revert back to regular-known elements or shatter into subatomic crap) after a few seconds. The movie implies that he somehow managed to transmute an element to another using the particle beam.

Comment: So using a particle accelerator to collide particles to create new ones is different to testing the results made from multiple permutations and combinations of existing ones? (which is what Jarvis calculated)

Comment: @Reanimation JARVIS used Earth based knowledge of particle physics which is far from perfect (you can't really calculate anything for probability-driven quantum world & that's why we need LHC experiments) to calculate an alien element.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: We can calculate new elements perfectly well. Indeed perfectly easily since it's simple addition: add one to the highest atomic number. We need particle accelerators to make the element EXIST - hence confirming our calculations. Without things like the LHC, all those calculations are just a bunch of chalk marks on the blackboard (or ink on paper, or bits in memory). The search for the Higgs Boson for example was a "search" - meaning trying to find something we think we know. Not actually discovering an unknown.

Comment: @slebetman Oh really? How do you suppose we got those numbers attached with atoms? Hundreds of experiments involved. Other that, those numbers just represents proportionality of attributes at rough scale. Check particle physics at precise level and you'll find addition doesn't work at all.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: Exactly what you said: those numbers just represent the number of protons in the atom. It's not that hard. Element 150 for example will have exactly 150 protons. We can even predict the number of neutrons it should have and weather it is an acid or a alkaline. We can calculate the half-life of such an element. In short, the only property that gives elements names is the number of protons - there is no need to create the element in order to name it. What we can't quite do is figure out the element's chemical properties. We can perdict it but not 100%.

Comment: But note that we still haven't quite figured out all the chemical properties of the most common element - carbon. So figuring out chemical properties of something is different than giving it a name.

Comment: @slebetman Hold on a second.. Did you say 150 protons? Drop century old ideas, please. You can't really count protons. At rough scale of proportionality, Helium atom contains twice that attribute than Hydrogen. This is how classical physics work. But, you can barely use it in particle accelerator.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: That's the DEFINITION of an atom. Yes, it's centuries old. So are computers. Doesn't mean we don't still use them.

Comment: @slebetman I am saying you can't predict a new element just by adding *integer* number of protons (It's just a coincidence that elements in periodic table have atomic number in integers in rough approximation). Here, word *number* is meaningless in context of modern definition of particles, too.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: The word number must be intergral because it is the number of protons. The modern definition of particles as excitation in fields doesn't lead to partial particles (for example 0.1 protons). As I've said, we can't predict chemical properties of elements with 100% certainty because we do not yet have a good model of what happens to the periodic table above element 118. But not knowing the chemical properties of an element is different from predicting an element. We know exactly what such elements would look like. We just aren't sure how it would behave.

Comment: Also, please don't confuse particle physics - which only behaves probabilistically when a particle doesn't interact with anything else in the universe - with atomic physics. Particles don't behave strangely when they interact with other particles - for example when they form an atom.

Comment: @slebetman In theory, we can have 2.2 protons. If you know quantum superposition, you won't try counting. BTW, you said something about deterministic behaviour when particles form atom. See a heap of radioactive atoms. One atom bleeds its instability at this time and another (fully identical atom) after billions of years. Now, what would you say?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: What theory would that be? Quantum superposition only exists while a particle isn't interacting with anything else in the universe (the term used is "observed" but observation is merely interaction it doesn't require an actual "observer"). Once interaction/observation happens quantum superposition collapses. Since all protons in an atom interact with each other they can't be in superposition. Thus they're always in integer numbers. "Instability" as you call it are quantum - that means they happen in integer numbers.

Comment: If the atom becomes "unstable" it loses an integer number of protons - this is how we transmute elements - by knocking protons into or out of the nucleus. A photon that is knocked out of an atom is then alone and can exhibit wave-like behavior until it encounters something else in the universe (another particle).

Comment: Electrons on the other hand can be in superposition. Because they're very-very far away from the nucleus to be practically non-interacting/non-observed.

Comment: Superposition was just an example to show the behavior of quantum world over normal world counting. And, I talked about non-deterministic behavior of instability bleeding to show where our particle physics fails. We don't know why one atom holds its instability for 5 minutes and another for thousands years. Plus, particles have all rights to exist in non-integral numbers. And, there's no reason why an alien element can't be made up of other elementary particles. So, how do you suppose any genius can theoretically calculate such things?

Comment: It wasn't Vibranium

Comment: It was not vibranium; it was actually an element that Stark later named "Badassium".